# Same message print 8 times when it should print only once in tic-tac-toe game

Tags: c#, windows

Well, here I have a tic-tac-toe app. I have made it properly, but it has a small issue. When it is a draw, it shows me the message like 8 times and I am not able to correct this alone. Everything else is alright. In the tutorial I have found it doesn't adress this specific issue, so what am I doing wrong?

```cs
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string[] table = new string[9];
        int countTurn = 0;
        public String returnSymbol(int turn)
        {
            if (turn % 2 == 0)
            {
                return "O";
            }
            else
                return "X";
        }
        public System.Drawing.Color determineColor(string symbol)
        {
            if(symbol.Equals("X"))
            {
                return System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen;
            }
            else
            {
                return System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
            }
        }
        public void CheckDraw()
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++)
            {
                if (table[i] != null)
                    count++;


                if (count == 9)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("That's a draw!", "We have no winner :(", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                }
            }
        }
        public void checkForWinner()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<8; i++)
            {
                string combination = "";
                int one=0, two=0, three = 0;
                switch(i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        combination = table[0] + table[4] + table[8];
                        one = 0;
                        two = 4;
                        three = 8;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        combination = table[2] + table[4] + table[6];
                        one = 2;
                        two = 4;
                        three = 6;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        combination = table[0] + table[1] + table[2];
                        one = 0;
                        two = 1;
                        three = 2;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        combination = table[3] + table[4] + table[5];
                        one = 3;
                        two = 4;
                        three = 5;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        combination = table[6] + table[7] + table[8];
                        one = 6;
                        two = 7;
                        three = 8;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        combination = table[0] + table[3] + table[6];
                        one = 0;
                        two = 3;
                        three = 6;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        combination = table[1] + table[4] + table[7];
                        one = 1;
                        two = 4;
                        three = 7;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        combination = table[2] + table[5] + table[8];
                        one = 2;
                        two = 5;
                        three = 8;
                        break;
                }
                if(combination.Equals("OOO"))
                {
                    changeColor(one);
                    changeColor(two);
                    changeColor(three);
                    MessageBox.Show("O has won the game!", "We have a winner!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
                else
                    if(combination.Equals("XXX"))
                {
                    changeColor(one);
                    changeColor(two);
                    changeColor(three);
                    MessageBox.Show("X has won the game!", "We have a winner!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
                else
                {
                    CheckDraw();
                }
            }
        }
        public void reset()
        {
            button1.Text = "";
            button2.Text = "";
            button3.Text = "";
            button4.Text = "";
            button5.Text = "";
            button6.Text = "";
            button7.Text = "";
            button8.Text = "";
            button9.Text = "";
            button1.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
            button2.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
            button3.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
            button4.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
            button5.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
            button6.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
            button7.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
            button8.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
            button9.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
            countTurn = 0;
            table = new string[9];
        }
        public void changeColor(int number)
        {
            switch(number){
                case 0:
                    button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    button3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    button4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    button5.BackColor= System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    button6.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    button7.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    button8.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    button9.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countTurn++;
            table[0]=returnSymbol(countTurn);
            button1.BackColor = determineColor(table[0]);
            button1.Text = table[0];
            checkForWinner();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countTurn++;
            table[1] = returnSymbol(countTurn);
            button2.BackColor = determineColor(table[1]);
            button2.Text = table[1];
            checkForWinner();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countTurn++;
            table[2] = returnSymbol(countTurn);
            button3.BackColor = determineColor(table[2]);
            button3.Text = table[2];
            checkForWinner();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countTurn++;
            table[3] = returnSymbol(countTurn);
            button4.BackColor = determineColor(table[3]);
            button4.Text = table[3];
            checkForWinner();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countTurn++;
            table[4] = returnSymbol(countTurn);
            button5.BackColor = determineColor(table[4]);
            button5.Text = table[4];
            checkForWinner();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countTurn++;
            table[5] = returnSymbol(countTurn);
            button6.BackColor = determineColor(table[5]);
            button6.Text = table[5];
            checkForWinner();
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countTurn++;
            table[6] = returnSymbol(countTurn);
            button7.BackColor = determineColor(table[6]);
            button7.Text = table[6];
            checkForWinner();
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countTurn++;
            table[7] = returnSymbol(countTurn);
            button8.BackColor = determineColor(table[7]);
            button8.Text = table[7];
            checkForWinner();
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countTurn++;
            table[8] = returnSymbol(countTurn);
            button9.BackColor = determineColor(table[8]);
            button9.Text = table[8];
            checkForWinner();
        }

        private void TryAgainBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the answer has already been posted but it's always a good idea to remember that you can use `break;` to exit a loop.

Comment: You need to early exit the loop in `checkForWinner()` when a win or draw is detected.

Comment: A `for switch` is always a code smell

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `CheckDraw` method is called within the outer for loop `for(int i=0;i<8; i++)`. Change `CheckDraw` to return a bool like so:

```cs
public bool CheckDraw()
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++)
    {
        if (table[i] != null)
            count++;

        if (count == 9)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("That's a draw!", "We have no winner :(", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then in `CheckForWinner()` change

```cs
                else
                {
                    CheckDraw();
                }
```

to

```cs
                else
                {
                    if (CheckDraw())
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

As a side note: I think your implementation allows to change the status of fields that have already been played. So you can win the game by changing an O to an X...

Comment: Well I solved the problem with the checkdraw with the help of a bool, but how do I block the change from an O to an X? Thanks by the way a lot

Comment: @RaresPetrescu One possibility would be to test the condition in your `button_click` handlers. Something like `if (table[0] != string.Empty) return;` . You should preferably move all the button_click handlers to a function (taking the button and button number as argument)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually simplify your `CheckDraw` function to the following

```
public void CheckDraw()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++)
    {
        //on the first `null` entry it can't be a draw anymore, so return
        if (table[i] == null)
            return;
    }

    //if the loop found a value in all cells it's a draw ...
    MessageBox.Show("That's a draw!", "We have no winner :(", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

or even simpler if you use LINQ

```
public void CheckDraw()
{
    if (table.All(x => x != null)) {
        MessageBox.Show("That's a draw!", "We have no winner :(", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

But that function is not your real problem. The problem is in `checkForWinner`. You should exit once you found a winner. And only if none of the winning situations leads to a winner, check also for a draw.

```
public void checkForWinner() 
{
    for(int i=0;i<8; i++)
    {
        string combination = "";
        int one=0, two=0, three = 0;
        switch(i)
        {
            ...
        }

        if(combination.Equals("OOO"))
        {
            ...
            MessageBox.Show("O has won the game!", "We have a winner!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;  //return from checkforWinner as we already have a winner
        }
        else if(combination.Equals("XXX"))
        {
            ...
            MessageBox.Show("X has won the game!", "We have a winner!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;  //return from checkforWinner as we already have a winner
        }
    }
    //if we arrived here, it could still be a draw ...
    checkDraw();
}
```

You could also dramatically simplify your `checkForWinner` if you create a List of winning situations beforehand and then just iterate over the situations and check it. Because the checking is always the same: Check if the three entries in the table are equal. If yes, the respective player has won the game ...

```
public void checkForWinner() 
{
    var winningList = new List<(int a, int b, int c)> {
        (0, 1, 2),
        (3, 4, 5),
        //...
    };
        
    foreach (var t in winningList) {
        if (table[t.a] != null && table[t.a] == table[t.b] && table[t.a] == table[t.c]) {
            changeColor(t.a);
            changeColor(t.b);
            changeColor(t.c);
            MessageBox.Show($"{table[t.a]} has won the game!", ...);
            return;  //return from checkforWinner as we already have a winner
        }
    }
    //if we arrived here, it could still be a draw ...
    CheckDraw();
}
```

And as said in another comment: Most of your button click handlers only differ in the index of the table lookup. You could easily attach a `Tag` to each button (or determine it even from the name of the button)   so you could use the same clickhandler for all buttons instead of having to repeat the same code 9 times ...